# Spring MVC Page is not rendering the success page using simpleformcontroller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Iam wrote simple spring mvc apps.But I unable to redirect one page to another page. I  mentioned code snippet below

Claims-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"> 
        <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props><prop key="/loginpage.htm">loginFormController</prop></props>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginFormController" class="com.aims.controller.LoginFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="commandName"><value>LoginFormCommand</value></property>
    <property name="commandClass"><value>com.aims.commands.LoginFormCommand</value></property>
    <property name="validator"><ref bean="loginformValidator"/></property> 
    <property name="formView"><value>loginpage</value></property>
    <property name="successView"><value>body</value></property>

    </bean>
    <bean id="loginformValidator" class="com.aims.validator.LoginFormValidator"/>


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"><value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value></property> 

        <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Controller:

```
public class LoginFormController extends SimpleFormController {     
  public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command, BindException bindException) throws Exception {
 System.out.println("LoginFormController:onSubmit============");
 LoginFormCommand loginform = (LoginFormCommand) command;
 System.out.println("username" + loginform.getUsername() + "Password"
            + loginform.getPassword()); 
 return   new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/WEB-INF/view/jsp/"
            + getSuccessView()));
 }}
```

I have two jsp one is

```
Webroot>loginpage.jsp
view->jsp>body.jsp
```

When the browser opens its automatically called loginpage.jsp(web.xml>welecome-file) and after success iam trying to call view->jsp>body.jsp.But it doesn't move to body.jsp.Please need help.

Answer (score 2):

With a redirect view, you must specify the actual URL of the target, not a path to an internal jsp. Instead of rendering a jsp, Spring MVC will redirect the user to this URL.

Example: `new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/example/helloworld.html"))`.

Of course, the target has to exist.